# ExtJs 4.1: Destroy components on closing a dynamically created tab

Tags: extjs, tabs, extjs4, extjs4.1, tabpanel

I am creating new ExtJs tabpanels and rendering panels inside it programmatically.
The panels (rendered inside tabs) are all written in separate JS files.

Opening, rendering and closing of the tabs is working completely fine.
But when I debug the code I see that the previous components of the closed tabs are still active in the memory. As a result of which the functioning of the components gets affected when the tab is reopened.

I want to destroy all the components inside the tab panels (if ExtJs, for some reasons, is not able to do it).

How can I do this?

Below is a sample code which I am trying:

Main Tab:

```
var tabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
    id : 'screensTabPanel',
    layout : 'fit',
    enableTabScroll : true,
    height : Ext.getBody().getStyleSize().height - 60,
    activeTab : 0,
    //enableTabScroll : true,
    autoScroll : true,
    autoRender : true,
    border : false,
    plugins : [ {
        ptype : 'tabscrollermenu',
        maxText : 30,
        pageSize : 5
    } ]
});
```

Dynamic Tab object:

```
var tabConfig = {
            title : text,
            bodyPadding : 3,
            closeAction:'destroy',
            autoScroll : true,
            id : 'tab' + id,
            closable : closable,
            loader : {
                loadMask : 'loading...',
                autoLoad : true,
                url : url,
                scripts : true,
                params : {
                    userId : 1
                },
            border : false,
            appId : appIdx,
            screenId : screenId,
            gridType : gridType,
            listeners : {
                beforeclose : function(tab) {
                    debugger;
                    tab.removeAll(); //I tried doing this
                    tab.destroy(); //I tried doing this as well
                    return true;
                }
            }
        };
```

Internal Panel code:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.window.VisualSQLQueryBuilder', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
itemId: 'qb-VisualSQLQueryBuilderId',
renderTo: Ext.Element.get('divQueryBuilder'),
layout: {
    type: 'border'
},
listeners:{
    beforerender: function(thisa, eOpts ){
        debugger;
        /*if(Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#qb-VisualSQLQueryBuilderId").length > 1){
            Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#qb-VisualSQLQueryBuilderId")[0].destroy();
        }*/
        Tab.MainTab = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#qb-VisualSQLQueryBuilderId")[Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#qb-VisualSQLQueryBuilderId").length - 1];
    }
},
items: [ .... screen components ... ]
});
```

Add Panel object to tab:

```
addedTab = ExtCont.add(tabConfig);
addedTab.show();
ExtCont.setActiveTab(addedTab);
```

Now this is what happens:

1. Open Tab (Name - Query Builder)
2. Code reaches the `beforerender` listener.
3. `Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#qb-VisualSQLQueryBuilderId")` has only one object inside it.
4. Everything works fine.

Now the problem starts

1. Close the tab
2. Code reaches `beforeclose` listener. Trying tab.removeAll() and tab.destroy()
3. Reopen tab - Query Builder
4. Code reaches `beforerender` listener.
5. Now `Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#qb-VisualSQLQueryBuilderId")` has two objects inside it. So it is retaining the object of the tab opened first time. And the second one is that of the tab opened just now.

How do I ensure whenever a tab is closed all its components get smoothly destroyed?

Comment: if you create a fiddle on sencha fiddle I can try to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it will be very difficult to create a fiddle for this :( I will try in free time if am able to.

Answer (score 1):

from [TabPanel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel):

> Note: By default, a tab's close tool destroys the child tab Component and all its     descendants. This makes the child tab Component, and all its descendants unusable. To enable re-use of a tab, configure the TabPanel with autoDestroy: false.

so it could really be an ExtJS Bug cause `autoDestroy: true` is default. maybe you could open a ticket.

Comment: since I am doing this manually(programmatically), I suspect there might be some miss from my side and ExtJs is not able to know the child components. And hence it is not able to destroy them.

Comment: I just noticed that you use `renderTo` instead of 'tabs.add()' why didn't you use this method?

Comment: I am adding the object of `tabConfig` using `tab.add()`. I will update the code in the question. But yes I am also providing a `<div>` id, inside a JSP, against the `renderTo` property. Do you think that might  be the reason?

Comment: I don't know, I have no idea., seems very strange.

Comment: Ok. One question. When I check the `Ext.ComponentManager.all.map`, I see only those components for whom I have specified an id explicitly and not any other components. Does this mean rest of the objects are still in the memory? How do I confirm it or whatever I have been trying is enough to confirm that the components from previous tabs are still alive.